# building a random timer circuit that will delay from 0 to 3 sec after trigger input relay output

Tags: timer, solid-state-relay, random

need some help to build a random timer circuit that will delay from 0 to 3 sec after trigger input relay output
Have looked at a number of 555 circuits but no monostable or astable ic seems capable

Comment: Please capitalise and punctuate your sentences for legibility and credibility.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be a small microcontroller with a pseudo-random delay routine. Doing this with a 555 wold be quite difficult.